# How to set common ansible_user to all hosts in a group?

Tags: ansible, openstack, ansible-inventory

Does anyone know if ansible enables users share the same `ansible_user` settings across all hosts included in a group?  This feature would be particularly useful  when using some cloud computing platforms such as OpenStack, which enables users to launch multiple instances that share the same config, such as user accounts and SSH keys.

Comment: add your ansible_user var in `inventory/group_vars/my_group/vars.yml` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several behavioral parameters you can configure to modify the way Ansible connects to your host. Among them is the `ansible_user` variable. You can set it per `host` pr per `group`. You can also define a general `ansible_user` variable under the `all` hosts group, that you override at the `group` or `host` level.

If you were writing your inventory in just one `hosts.yml` file you'd do it like this:

```
all:
  children:
    ubuntu_linux:
      hosts:
        ubuntu_linux_1:
        ubuntu_linux_2:
    aws_linux:
      hosts:
        aws_linux_host_1:
        aws_linux_host_2:
        aws_linux_host_3:
      vars:
        ansible_user: ec2-user
  vars:
    ansible_host: ubuntu
```

And, if you are using a directory to create your inventory, you can set it inside the `./inventory/group/vars.yml` file.

Check the ["Connecting to hosts: behavioral inventory parameters"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters) section of Ansible docs to see what other parameters you can configure.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion helped a lot.  Kudos!